# Java dates zone format to simple format

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

is it possible to convert this kind of format in Java (probably ISO 8601)  `"2022-11-11T00:00:00" or this "2022-11-11T12:00:00+01:00"` which comes as a string, to simple format "yyyy-mm-dd" with Date or Time kind of classes, or it should be done with string methods?

Example:

```
you receive this -> "2022-11-11T00:00:00"
you convert to this -> "2022-11-11"
```

Comment: That's no date, that's a string. If you will ALWAYS receive it formated as you posted I would use String methods (`received.split("T")[0]`)

Comment: You shouldn't use `SimpleDateFormat` at all, but rather classes from the `java.time` package. `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` will do the job.

Comment: Looks like you might want to use `java.time.OffsetDateTime`, `LocalDateTime` and `LocalDate`…

Comment: "but it can be with other letter of course" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: Yes, it is possible and adequate using date and time classes, more precisely [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) that others have already mentioned. And yes, the formats are [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Recommended way: `java.time`

If you need to calculate anything based on the values or maybe find out the day of week, you will be best adviced using `java.time`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example input in ISO format
    String first = "2022-11-11T00:00:00";
    String second = "2022-11-11T12:00:00+01:00";
    // parse them to suitable objects
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(first);
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(second);
    // extract the date from the objects (that may have time of day and offset, too)
    LocalDate firstDate = ldt.toLocalDate();
    LocalDate secondDate = odt.toLocalDate();
    // format them as ISO local date, basically the same format as the input has
    String firstToBeForwarded = firstDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
    String secondToBeForwarded = secondDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE); 
    // print the results (or forward them as desired)
    System.out.println(firstToBeForwarded);
    System.out.println(secondToBeForwarded);
}
```

The output of this example is

```
2022-11-11
2022-11-11
```

---

### Not recommended, but possible: `String` manipulation

If you just have to

- extract the date part (year, month of year and day of month) and
- you are sure it will always be the first 10 characters of the `String`s you receive

you could simply take the first 10 characters:

```java
String toBeForwarded = "2022-11-11T00:00:00".substring(0, 10);
```

This line would store `"2022-11-11"` in `toBeForwarded`.

Comment: Fine answer. I’d prefer to parse into a `LocalDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` under all circumstances for the sake of validation. Furthermore one may then (depending on taste) verify that the time of day is 00:00 and any offset is as expected.

Comment: Thanks, @OleV.V. , I rearranged the answer in order to point out the recommended solution.

Comment: I found it helpful rather than authorative